# SELECT INTO STATEMENT INSIDE A SQL PROCEDURE THROWING AN ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I want to store a avalue of select statement into a variable and then update my table using that variable within the procedure but there is an error . I still dont know its only returning one column then also below error exists.
**exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.**

Here is the example of demo code.Can anyone please give me an alternative of what else I can do here to make it work since I have many such plsql statement to populate table columns

```
create or replace procedure pcountry (country IN Varchar) is
var_date Date;
begin

select date into var_date from countrytable where country=country;

update newtable
set date=var_date
where country=country
commit;

end pcountry;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your PL/SQL variables/arguments with the same name as columns. The SQL engine will look for the `country` value in the local SQL scope in preference to the outer PL/SQL scope so `country=country` is (assuming non-`NULL` values) the same as `1=1` and you will match all rows.

Assuming each `country` is unique then:

```sql
create or replace procedure pcountry (
  v_country IN COUNTRY_TABLE.COUNTRY%TYPE
) is
  var_date COUNTRY_TABLE."DATE"%TYPE;
begin
  select "DATE"
  into var_date
  from countrytable
  where country=v_country;

  update newtable
  set "DATE"=var_date
  where country=v_country
end pcountry;
/
```

*Also, `DATE` is a reserved word and you cannot use is as an unquoted identifier.*

You can combine it into a single SQL statement using `MERGE`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE pcountry (
  v_country IN COUNTRY_TABLE.COUNTRY%TYPE
) is
  var_date COUNTRY_TABLE."DATE"%TYPE;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO newtable n
  USING (SELECT *
         FROM   countrytable
         WHERE  country = v_country) c
  ON (c.country = n.country)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET "DATE" = c."DATE";
END pcountry;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the name of your procedure'input argument since you have a column with the same name in your table. Oracle is interpretting your where clause
`where country = country` as `where 1 = 1` which is always true. So it returns more rows instead of one row.

```sql
create or replace procedure pcountry (country_in IN Varchar) is
var_date Date;
begin

select date into var_date from countrytable where country = country_in ;

update newtable
set date=var_date
where country= country_in 
commit;

end pcountry;
```

Comment: Thankyou for the prompt response. It works. I was wondering what was wrong with it but the answer came when demo code was mapped.

Answer (score 1):

Skip `select`, switch to `merge`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pcountry (par_country IN varchr2)
IS
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO newtable n
        USING countrytable c
           ON (c.country = n.country)
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
      UPDATE SET n.date_column = c.date_column
   WHERE n.country = par_country;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as has been explained in other answers, is that it makes no sense to expect `country` in a condition like `country = country` to mean *different* things on the two sides of the equal sign. The name `country` has more than one meaning - then a set of rules is applied to figure out which meaning is to be accepted each time the name is used. That is usually the narrowest context ("scope") in which the name exists; in this case, the name exists in the table referenced in the SQL statement, so that's what `country` means there.

One solution is simple - use a different name for the parameter used in the procedure. This has also been shown in the other answers.

There is another solution though. It might be preferred if your procedure was already very long, it used a parameter name like `country`, and now you would need to add some code where you need to use this name in a SQL statement. It would be pretty time-consuming to change the parameter name everywhere. Happily, PL/SQL understands qualified names. `country` (where you used it in the `where` clause) is the column name for the table referenced in the query. But if you write `pcountry.country` on the right-hand side, *qualifying* the variable name with the name of the procedure, no confusion would arise anymore.

```
... where country = pcountry.country
```

will achieve the same result as the other proposed answers in this thread. The right-hand side is the parameter or variable coming from the procedure, not the column name from the table.

Note that you could also qualify the left-hand side:

```
... where countrytable.country = pcountry.country
```

and perhaps this would be clearer to future readers.

However, this would ***not*** help:

```
... where countrytable.country = country
```

can you see why?